# Window object passes typeof object test, but hasOwnProperty causes error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a popup window (`opened_window = window.open()`) has been closed before the document/javascript has loaded in the popup window, since if javascript hasn't loaded then I can't handle the `onunload` event in the child window to communicate with the parent window and let it know the popup has closed.

When I close the popup before the document has loaded and do a `console.log(opened_window)` from the parent window, it shows that `opened_window` is an object and contains the properties `closed` which is set to `true`, and `opener` which is `null`.

So, I did this:

```
if (opened_window !== null && typeof opened_window === 'object')
{
    if (opened_window.hasOwnProperty('closed') &&
        opened_window.closed === true &&
        opened_window.hasOwnProperty('opener') &&
        opened_window.opener === null)
    {
        opened_window = null;
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: undocked_window.hasOwnProperty is not a function`. This is very confusing to me, since it passed the `typeof opened_window === 'object'` test already, which means `opened_window` is an object, so why would `.hasOwnProperty` then cause an error? It's my understanding that `.hasOwnProperty` will work on any object.

Comment: `Object.create(null).hasOwnProperty === undefined`. As `hasOwnProperty` is defined on the main object prototype, an object without a prototype will not have it.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty.call(opened_window, 'closed') `

Comment: @dandavis That will only work if the global object inherits from `Object.prototype`. But that's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Oriol: yikes, where should i look out for that?

Comment: @dandavis [ES5-15.1 The Global Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) says "*The values of the [[Prototype]] and [[Class]] internal properties of the global object are implementation-dependent*". And [ES6-18 The Global Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-object) says "*The value of the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the global object is implementation-dependent*". Not sure if W3C defines it for browsers, though.

Comment: @Oriol: well, i was just wondering if there's some common hole in the coverage, like IE or node or something. i think i may have used this somewhere and hadn't noticed any issues, so was wondering if i need to track it down and fix it, or just not use it going forward? i tested a bit and it seems a common pattern, is there anything you know of off the top of your head?

Comment: @dandavis Yes, I don't know any browser in which `window` doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`. But better don't rely on it.

Comment: @Oriol: i'll change my evil ways, thanks for the links and head-up! i'd actually shifted to using the function's name.hasOwn, as i was worried about lexical poisoning and V8's perf on Object.prototype.has and i can keep it purer/faster with a local handle. aside: it would be a safer browser if global didn't inherit as it would protect against "constructor.constructor" leakage in "use strict"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange, but not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`.

For example:

```
Object.create(null).hasOwnProperty('foo'); // error
```

But you can borrow the method:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Object.create(null), 'foo'); // false
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that, it worked perfectly. I'll mark this as accepted just as soon as the 5 minutes is up.